# Django, how to access models inside a model through a model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models that have a many-to-one relationship between them.

```
from django.db import models


class Continent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, unique=True, primary_key=False)
    c = Continent.objects.get(id=1)
    countries = c.country_set.all()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]


class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    capital = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, unique=True, primary_key=False)
    continent = models.ForeignKey('Continent')
    population = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    area = PositiveIntegerField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]
```

I want the countries of a continent to be accessible through a countries attribute within the Continent model. I tried to follow the relationship "backward" like in the documentation (link below), but can't get it to work. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a `related_name` parameter in the `ForeignKey` relation. This will automatically add a field with that name to the `Continent` model.

So this is how your models will look (note the 'related_name' parameter in `Country.continent` foreign key field):

```
class Continent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, unique=True, primary_key=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]


class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    capital = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, unique=True, primary_key=False)
    continent = models.ForeignKey('Continent', related_name='countries')
    population = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    area = PositiveIntegerField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
def test():
    c = Continent.objects.get(id=1)
    for country in c.countries.all():
        print(c.name)
```

---

`country_set` is the default name used as the related name. You don't need to set it as an explicit field in the `Continent` class. It is created behind the scenes.